# Tunnel URL not found (it might not be ready yet), falling back to LAN URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, vue.js, expo

After `expo start` , `expo r --tunnel`, `expo start --tunnel` I'm getting this error :

```
Tunnel URL not found (it might not be ready yet), falling back to LAN URL.
```

and sometimes :

```
Error starting tunnel Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
    |     property '_httpMessage' -> object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
    --- property 'socket' closes the circle
```

My environment info:

```
Expo CLI 5.0.3 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Linux 5.13 Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)
      Shell: 5.0.17 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 14.0.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.0.0/bin/node
      npm: 8.3.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.0.0/bin/npm
    npmPackages:
      @expo/metro-config: ^0.2.2 => 0.2.8 
      expo: ~44.0.0 => 44.0.0 
      react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1 
      react-dom: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1 
      react-native: 0.64.3 => 0.64.3 
      react-native-web: 0.17.1 => 0.17.1 
    Expo Workflow: managed
```

Please, help me! Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

it may contain various reason, try these :

- use latest version of expo-cli by running

  npm install -g expo-cli

> - also i highly recommend you to reboot your phone or clear you expo go cache on your phone

- third solution is to change your port from tunnel to lan by just run

  expo start